# Ramifications of returning an unsigned long when unsigned int is expected

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, types, core-foundation, nsuinteger

I'm implementing the `-hash` method on a class, which is supposed to return an `NSUInteger`.  My implementation for it was going to be similar to this:

```
- (NSUInteger) hash {
    return CFHash(self->cfObj);
}
```

Now, `CFHash` returns a `CFHashCode`, which is a `typedef`ed `unsigned long`, but as far as I'm aware an `NSUInteger` is either an `unsigned long` OR an `unsigned int`.

What sort of problems could I run into if I'm returning an `unsigned long` when the application expects an `unsigned int`?

Comment: I think there won't be any problems, even if there are hash collisions, they should be handled properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What platform are you compiling for? As you pointed out, an `NSUInteger` is either an unsigned long or unsigned int depending on whether or not your architecture is 32 or 64 bit. For 64-bit OS X apps, this is obviously fine.

I think you should be safe even on iOS or 32-bit OS X apps. The [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFTypeRef/Reference/reference.html) describe the return type of `CFHash`:

```
An integer of type CFHashCode that represents a hashing value for cf.
```

That's not a compelling reason, but the [default implementation of `hash` apparently uses `CFHash` anyway](http://books.google.ca/books?id=LFaxcuKxVf0C&pg=PA366&lpg=PA366&dq=iOS+CFHash+documation&source=bl&ots=Nf0kFUfk97&sig=dNta4rgMttmpI5kzG-ugXYlaNHY&hl=en&sa=X&ei=8FdwT5qMHYa20AHOt_XPBg&ved=0CD0Q6AEwAg#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Comment: I'm compiling for ios, but I'm not sure whether this was 32 or 64-bit. My main worry was that returning a long would cause some sort of overflow on 32-bit systems, but from your answer, this isn't something I have to worry about?

Comment: You should be fine - iOS is 32-bit, but you shouldn't get any collisions using `CFHash` with integers.